# force mutter to draw windows separately

Tags: gnome-shell, window, mutter

I'm currently using a tools (cssh) to open a lot of different xterm windows on my monitor at once. But some of them are drawn on top of each other, though there is free space to have them separate.

[image: screenshot on second monitor] (windows are undecorated using devilspie2)

How can I force mutter (GNOME shell?) to make some space between them, so they don't appear on top of each other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like cssh has some options you can set for this purpose. You can add the following lines to `$HOME/.clusterssh/config`, which should fix the overlap:

```
# reserve space for the gnome-shell top bar
screen_reserve_top = <height of top bar>
# use all the space at the bottom
screen_reserve_bottom = 0
```

The windows likely overlap because cssh calculates the positions based on having the first row at the very top of the screen, but gnome-shell actually the first row of windows down so they don't overlap with the top bar.